# To move recent SQL Server backup files from one machine to another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL query to move backup file from one machine to another. Here i need to specify each backup name to the variable @bkpFileName1. Actually, i need to move every backup file that is taken recently.I have to select each backupfile from my disk Drive and move it accordingly.How can i do it??

My Query :

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE

declare @date datetime
declare @dbname nvarchar(40)
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @srcbkpLocation nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @destbkpLocation nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @bkpFileName nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @bkpFileName1 nvarchar(4000)

set @destbkpLocation='\\ntp-228\Share_H\Monish'

SET @srcbkpLocation = 'E:\bckup\demo1'

SET @bkpFileName1 = 'WSI_NBQ_Dev_30_10_18.bak'



SET @cmd = 'robocopy '+@srcbkpLocation+' '+@destbkpLocation+' 
'+@bkpFileName1+' '+'/MOV'
 print @cmd
 EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd, NO_OUTPUT

  EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0
  RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
  GO

  EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
  RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
   GO
```

Comment: *Don't* use a sql query for that. Just execute the command line. If this runs as part of a job, add it as a cmd step. The very fact that you have to weaken security to use this should be a red flag

Comment: i think its not possible to schedule command line as sql server job

Comment: Try it. It was always possible. It's one of the 12 step types: `Operating System (CmdExec)`.

Comment: @SurajKumar why do that at all when such a service is already provided by SQL Server (SQL Server Agent) or the operating system (Task Scheduler) itself? Besides, no DBA would allow installing an unknown program for very valid reliability and security reasons.

Comment: Clicking `Help` button on the `New Job Step` wizard you'll find the [options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/job-step-properties-new-job-step-general-page?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(sql13.ag.job.stepgeneral.f1)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=sql-server-2017) for all step types, including cmd and powershell types. The [Manage Job Steps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/manage-job-steps?view=sql-server-2017#executable-programs-and-operating-system-commands-as-job-steps) page explains the various types.

Comment: Another way to move many files from one location to another is SSIS package with Filesystem Task. Package then can be scheduled with SQL Server Agent job